# Why is the output different from the desired output in the case of class vs Inheritance?

Tags: c++, class, if-statement

In the code below if statement does not get executed and the desired output is different from the output.

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>

class Person{
public:
    int age;
    Person(int initialAge);
    void amIOld();
    void yearPasses();
};

Person::Person(int initialAge){
    // Add some more code to run some checks on initialAge


if (initialAge < 0)
{
    age = 0;
cout << "Age is not valid, setting age to 0." << endl;
}

 else (initialAge = age)
 ;


}

void Person::amIOld(){
    // Do some computations in here and print out the correct statement to the console 
    if (age < 13)
    cout << "You are young." << endl;

    else if (age >= 13 && age < 18)
    cout << "You are a teenager."<< endl;

    else(cout << "You are old."<< endl)
    ;

}

void Person::yearPasses(){
    // Increment the age of the person in here
age ++;
}

int main(){
int t;
int age;
cin >> t;
for(int i=0; i < t; i++) {
    cin >> age;
    Person p(age);
    p.amIOld();
    for(int j=0; j < 3; j++) {
        p.yearPasses(); 
    }
    p.amIOld();
  
    cout << '\n';
}

return 0;
```

}

The output is different then the desired output. I can't understand why does the else satetment is not executed in the code given above. I am relatively new to coding.

### **Sample Input**

```
    4
   -1
    10
    16
    18
```

---

### **Sample Output**

```
    Age is not valid, setting age to 0.
    You are young.
    You are young.

    You are young.
    You are a teenager.

    You are a teenager.
    You are old.

    You are old.
    You are old
```

---

### **My Output**

```
    Age is not valid, setting age to 0.
    You are young.
    You are young.
    You are young.
    You are young.
    You are young.
    You are young.
    You are young.
    You are young.
```

---

Help is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Voting to close as typo. `else (initialAge = age)` should be `else age = initialAge;` (the `()` are superfluous here, don't add them. They are needed after `if` to enclose the condition, but not for `else`).

Comment: This looks strange: `else (initialAge = age);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`age = initialAge;` not other way around.
And you better to do more tidy formatting, it's hard to see that part of code, hence mistake  might be looked over. E.g.

```
Person::Person(int initialAge) : age(initialAge)
{
    // Add some more code to run some checks on initialAge
    if (age < 0)
    {
       age = 0;
       cout << "Age is not valid, setting age to 0." << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Apology I will surely do better formatting next time.

Comment: @solicitate first person you do it for is yourself. Think of it as any other text, an essay, an explanation of your way of thinking. Alot of mistakes can be caught on that stage

Answer (score 1):

The assignment is the wrong way around

```
else (initialAge = age)
```

Should be;

```
else
  age = initialAge;
```

Better still, use a member initialiser list, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor